# Open a dialog using openDialog and pass an object parameter

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm developing a Firefox extension which has this code to open some dialog:

```
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");

function showPanel()
{
    let mainWindow = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");

    mainWindow.openDialog(data.url("ui/options.html"),
                          "Dictionary settings",
                          "chrome,centerscreen,dialog,modal,resizable,scrollbars,height=400,width=400",
                          { a: 123 });
}
```

On the dialog side, when I access `window.arguments[0]` I get an empty object with no fields.
If I pass primitives like strings and numbers, they are passed correctly to the dialog.

What's the problem with this code?

Regards,

Update:

As I won't be able to commit my code, I've created a whole branch of the project.
Please check this repository https://github.com/ashrafsabrym/firefox-dict-switcher

Using an object or array as parameter sends an empty object to the dialog, while primitives work well.

Comment: I haven't worked with dialogs, i prefer inline options but more the localized xhtml pages ( https://github.com/Noitidart/l10n/tree/xhtml-xul ). But this looks right, its interesting, did you see this example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Dialogs_and_Prompts#Passing_arguments_and_displaying_a_dialog ?

Comment: Dialogs definitely can pass objects as arguments. I do so in one of my add-ons without any issues. I'll see if I can investigate a bit further to determine why your code is not working.

Comment: @Makyen The addon I work on is open source and hosted on Github. When I commit the code, I'll let you inspect it yourself.

Comment: @Noitidart Maybe because I'm using HTML not XUL in the dialog?

Comment: @Makyen Maybe because I'm using HTML not XUL in the dialog?

Comment: Thats interesting @Ashraf it should still work, Im really confused, if you could make a simple repeatable test case and upload we can knock it out.

Comment: We are going to need more information, preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I have tried something close to what you have, using a static `{ a: 123 }` and sending `window.arguments[0].a` to the console (but with a `.xul` file). It worked fine. At a minimum, it would help quite a bit to have a minimal version of your *ui/options.html* and any associated JavaScript file so we can duplicate the problem and determine what is going on. If you were seeing nothing at all, I would guess at a scoping issue, but just affecting objects is strange.

Comment: @Makyen As I won't be able to commit my code, I've created a whole branch of the project. Please check this repository https://github.com/ashrafsabrym/firefox-dict-switcher Using an object or array as parameter sends an empty object to the dialog, while primitives work well.

Comment: @Noitidart As I won't be able to commit my code, I've created a whole branch of the project. Please check this repository https://github.com/ashrafsabrym/firefox-dict-switcher Using an object or array as parameter sends an empty object to the dialog, while primitives work well.

Comment: Hey @Ashraf can you please make it an xpi, i dont have the tools to install a cfx addon.

Comment: @Noitidart I've done so. You may get it from the root of the repository.